# Why is signal() still enabled after being called?

Tags: c, signals

Expected control-c to only work once. Working on an assignment and this section states that multiple calls to control-c should fail, and from what I've read I understand this is due to the fact that the signal needs to be re-enabled within the handler. Here is my setup.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void signalHandler(int);

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Sleep#%d\n", (i+1));
        sleep(1);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("Program Exiting");
    return 0;
}

void signalHandler(int signal) {
    printf("Jumped to interrupt handler\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

From what I've read and what I expect to happen - the signalHandler function should be called when the control-c command is given, the printf() statement should execute, and subsequent control-c commands should no longer respond because I have not re-enabled the signal. However this is not the case. Every control-c I input is received. I'm running this inside of Cygwin using Clang. Is there a default behavior that re-enabled signals implicitly?

Comment: Just a note - If you are program on a Posix compliant system you must be careful what functions you call in your signal handler... Not all functions are "async safe".. i.e. safe to be called from a signal handler .. On my Ubuntu system you can determine the safe calls by running "man 7 signal".

Comment: @TonyB I am aware of this, but appreciate the feedback. Every thread I've come across in relation to using signal() greatly emphasize this point. The use of printf within the handler is actually in the assignment notes.

Comment: There's a nice writeup of why `signal()` is horribly under-specified in POSIX and should be avoided in favor of `sigaction()` in the Linux manpages for `signal()`. One of the points is indeed the difference between the original Unix and SysV semantics (resetting the signal to `SIG_DFL`) and BSD (keeping the signal-handler set).

Comment: @EOF I'm not really familiar with POSIX. The setup is given to us in an assignment, and from what I've have seen the instructor has not updated his course notes since 2011 (yay college....), so I'm not too surprised.

Comment: @ScotMatson: As far as I remember, the workaround is that `signal()` itself is an async-safe function. So you can just call `signal()` in the signal--handler itself to decide how to handle the next signal that arrives.

Comment: @EOF This is true - it is actually the last part of the exercise in using signal. We re-enable signal() by making the first statement in the handler another call to signal(). But in my case on the step previous to this when *supposedly* signal() has been passed to the handler and has then been disabled... it actually isn't disabled. It just seems the assignment is heavily outdated unfortunately. Oh well.

Comment: On what platform are you developing ..?

Comment: @TonyB: He says "Cygwin with Clang" (meaning on Windows with Cygwin).

Comment: @TonyB Windows7, Cygwin terminal, clang compiler.

Comment: Note that you can configure `sigaction()` to set the signal handling to behave as you want/expect `signal()` to do it by passing the appropriate arguments to it, as well as having the signal handling behave the way it does by default (which is what you're observing). The assignment is not so much 'heavily outdated' as 'making inaccurate assumptions for your development environment'. The defined behaviour for `signal()` is deliberately lax to allow a variety of pre-existing implementations to conform to the standard. That means that you can get different behaviours from those implementations.